# Jenkins File parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I created a simple pipeline script where it passes parameters which are declared on my python script.
However, file parameter in my script seems not being stored on my jenkins workspace. Any idea why my file is not being uploaded? Any suggestion? Thank you so much

**pipeline script:**

```
pipeline
{
    options {
        buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '5', artifactNumToKeepStr: '5'))
    }
    
    agent {
        label "ubuntu-python"
    }
    parameters {
        file(
            name: 'USERS_XML',
            description: 'parse user.xml'
        )
    }
        // Global shell environment
    environment {
        HOME="${WORKSPACE}"
    }
    stages{
        stage('Checkout'){
            steps{
                checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'git', url: 'https://bitbucket.com/bitbucket/scm/~user/samplecode.git']]])
            }
        }
        stage('Python modules'){
            steps{
                sh """
                python3 --version
                pip3 --version
               
                #Install required modules
                pip3 install requests
                pip3 install TestLink-API-Python-client
                pip3 install openpyxl
                """
            }
        }
        stage('Get Testlink Users'){
            steps{
                sh label: 'Display testlink users', 
                script: '''
                
                python3 -u testlink.py "${USERS_XML}"
                    
                '''
            }
        }
    }
    post{
        success {
            archiveArtifacts allowEmptyArchive: true, artifacts: '**/*.xlsx', caseSensitive: false, onlyIfSuccessful: true
        }
    }
}
```

**Error message:**

```
+ python3 -u testlink.py   tl-server devKey users.xml
------- User List for tl-server -------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testlink.py", line 120, in <module>
    serverList()
  File "testlink.py", line 28, in serverList
    tree = ET.parse(""+USERS_XML+"") 
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1202, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 584, in parse
    source = open(source, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'users.xml'
```

Comment: I think the script would expect instead of `USERS_XML` just `users.xml`

Answer (score 0):

I think the old File paramter has some problems, in general I use the [file paramter plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/file-parameters/)

```
parameters {
  stashedFile description: 'test', name: 'users.xml'
}
 // ....
stages {
  stage('Test') {
    steps {
      unstash 'users.xml'
      sh 'cat users.xml'
    }
  }
}
```